# How to share instance across Angular application?

Tags: angular

I have a root bootstapped Angular element that I use in another app. It has input parameters:

```
<block-element [props]="props"></block-element>
```

Components looks like:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'block-element',
    templateUrl: './block-element.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./block-element.component.scss'],
})
export class BlockElementComponent implements OnInit {
    public block: Block;
    @Input() props: ReonMapProps = {};

    ngOnInit() {
        this.block = new Block(this.props) // Get properties outside 
    }
}
```

How to share `new Block()` across full Angular application?

Comment: You can create a service with `BehaviorSubject` and `Observable`, import it in your root module and declare that service in a `providers` array.

Answer (score 0):

If i am understand correctly then you need to access `"Block" class` in another module of same project right?

just you need to export this class & import in module.ts. so it can be accessible to any module in angular application

Comment: Block class it is custom class, has not injectable property it is core of library

Comment: can you please share some block of code like stackliz online it help to us to help you quickly

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a shared service and the service should have a field of Block Type.

Then you have to assign your block instance in the component to that field in your shared service.

Refer [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/5-ways-to-share-data-between-angular-components-d656a7eb7f96)